# jq json parser concate nested array object value

Tags: json, parsing, jq

Hi I have the below JSON file with nested object:

```
{
  "Maps": {
    "Campus": [
      {
        "name": "nus",
        "Building": [
          {
            "name": "sde1",
            "Floor": [
              {
                "name": "floor1"
              },
              {
                "name": "floor2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "sde2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ntu",
        "Building": [
          {
            "name": "ece1",
            "Floor": [
              {
                "name": "floor1"
              },
              {
                "name": "floor2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "ece2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to use `jq` to parse the above JSON file and get the below format:

```
nus>sde1>floor1
nus>sde1>floor2
ntu>ece1>floor1
ntu>ece1>floor2
```

basically I have to concatenate the `Campus Name` with `Building Name` and `Floor name` and put a `<` symbol in between.

If the nested object field `Floor` is not exist, ignore the parse and continue the next child object.

How to achieve that? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `jq` command:

```
jq '.Maps.Campus[]|"\(.name)>\(.Building[]|"\(.name)>\(.Floor[]?.name)")"' file.json
```

`jq` is smart enough to print the combinations of `.name` and `.Building[].name` since `.Building` is an array. The same action get's applied to `.Building[].name` and `Floor[]?.name`. `?` because floor is not always set.

Comment: Sorry, my initial post is wrong as I cannot post a long json code into stackoverflow, it always prompt me with "mostly code, please add more comments" warning. Now I have updated my JSON file and requirements. Thank you.

Comment: so for a nested json array, use mutliple piping `|` and `()` to nest those values together and construct the filter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses jq variables

```
  .Maps.Campus[]
| .name as $campus
| .Building[]
| .name as $bldg
| .Floor[]?
| .name as $floor
| "\($campus)>\($bldg)>\($floor)"
```